# Redirect speaker output to microphone

Tags: audio, speaker, audio-recording

I want to redirect speaker output of Android mobile to microphone, just like this person did it on Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/283687/redirect-speaker-output-to-microphone

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to record the speaker output, or send it to the other caller in a phone call? What phone do you have?

Comment: @DanHulme I've Padfone 2. I want to record the speaker output.